# while loop within each loop causing page to crash

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to excecute a while loop within an each loop in JQuery but it makes the page crash. Can this code be written in another way? What I'm trying to do is to add an elipsis when multiple lines of text overflow within multiple elements.

**HTML**

```
<div class="three-col-three-img-txt">
    <div class="txt-block">
        <div class="txt-entries">
            <div class="txt-entries-wrap">
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="txt-block">
        <div class="txt-entries">
            <div class="txt-entries-wrap">
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="txt-block">
        <div class="txt-entries">
            <div class="txt-entries-wrap">
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$( ".three-col-three-img-txt .txt-block" ).each(function() {
    var ph = $(this).find('.txt-entries .txt-entries-wrap');
    var p = $(this).find('.txt-entries .txt-entries-wrap p');
    var divh = $(this).find('.txt-entries').height();
    while ($(ph).outerHeight() > divh) {
         $(p).text(function (index, text) {
              return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? From what I can gather, your loop has no effect because `.txt-entries .txt-entries-wrap` does not exist.

Comment: When the `while` loop condition does not change -- in other words when there is no possibility of the the condition ever being `FALSE` -- the result is an `INIFINITE LOOP`. Infinite loops normally crush browsers. :(

Comment: wrap everything inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ... your jquery code ... })`

Comment: You should change your `while` loop to an `if` loop. `while` loops will run continuously until the condition is false

Comment: `.find()` searches descendant elements. Where are the descendants you are searching for in `.find('.txt-entries .txt-entries-wrap p')` and `.find('.txt-entries .txt-entries-wrap')`?

Comment: We need to see your css too, as that can affect the outcome of this code. Also, your sample html seems to be missing some elements, based on your js.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. So far, you are iterating through each `.txt-block`, and per each iteration you are iterating again with the `while` creating an infinite loop since nothing changes.

Comment: Based on your edit - I think what you are looking for is another `.each()` and then an `if` statement

Comment: @user1937021. Check out the edit on your HTML, if you think its correct leave it, if not, edit it to the right HTML we need to see

Comment: Made updates to the OP now

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to loop through each `.txt-block` , then another loop through each `.txt-entries`.. if thats the case you need to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".txt-block").each(function() {
        $(this).find('.txt-entries').each(function() {
            var ph = $(this).find('.txt-entries-wrap');
            var p = $(this).find('.txt-entries-wrap p');
            var divh = $(this).height();
            if ($(ph).outerHeight() > divh) {
                $(p).text(function (index, text) {
                     return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: it needs the while instead of if, else it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a while loop, because that is what your `.each()` function is doing - it is going through every `.three-col-three-img-text .txt-block` one by one.

Instead try using an `IF` statement:

```
if( $(ph).outerHeight() > divh ){
     $(p).text(function (index, text) {
          return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
     });
}
```

OR - if what you are trying ot accomplish is then looping through each of the `.txt-entries .txt-entries-wrap` you should use the `.each()` function again like this:

```
$(ph).each(function(){
    if($(this).outerHeight() > divh) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the purpose of the while loop in this case. He's looping until the height of the div is greater than x, and inside the loop, he's doing something that theoretically (depending on css) will increase the height.

Comment: @KevinB could be - need some more clarification from the OP as to what they are trying to accomplish. Just making a suggestion based on what I think. The clear issue is that there is an infinite loop.

Comment: Added more clarification to OP